# What are the Flux equivalents of debounce, throttleFirst, and throttleLast

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, project-reactor

`debounce`, `throttleFirst`, and `throttleLast` are most conspicuously absent from Project Reactor's Flux. Do they have any counterparts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `sample` operators are the once relating to the behavior you're searching for.

[`sampleTimeout`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sampleTimeout-java.util.function.Function-) could be used as `debounce`.
[`sampleFirst`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sampleFirst-java.time.Duration-) could be used as `throttleFirst`.
[`sample`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sample-java.time.Duration-) could be used as `throttleLast`.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling to understand how to use `sampleTimeout` to do a `debounce` so I though I would put it here in case someone else is looking for this:

The would be equivalent to a `debounce` of 200ms

```java
myFlux.sampleTimeout(u -> Mono.empty().delaySubscription(Duration.ofMillis(200)))
```

Comment: I'm trying to write a test showing a difference in behaviour between that and `myFlux.sample(Duration.ofMillis(200))` and so far I haven't managed it - what do you think the difference is?

Comment: That would do a fixed sampling every 200ms. So a window would never last more than 200ms whereas with what I did the windows will last as long as you have elements being received less than 200ms apart from each others. The [marbles in the documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#sample-java.time.Duration-) may help.

Comment: Thanks. OK, I want it to emit every window, just not more often, so `sample(Duration)` is fine for my use case.